# Jquery syntax for "also do this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

This is possibly an easy question, but do to my lack of eduction in jQuery I don't know the answer. And I'm just curious.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
jQuery("a").click(function() {

    jQuery(this).siblings().fadeToggle() "and also" .toggleClass("foo");

});
```

Instead of repeating the first half of it, like this:

```
jQuery("a").click(function() {

    jQuery(this).siblings().fadeToggle();
    jQuery(this).siblings().toggleClass("foo");

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery methods allow chaining, ie most of the jQuery methods(excepts the getter methods and methods which does filtering or traversing etc) returns the jQuery object on which a method was called on, so you can simply add the call to the second function after `fadeToggle()`

```
jQuery(this).siblings().fadeToggle().toggleClass("foo");
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew it would be simple.